# Why can't some functions be integrated?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, functional-calculus

There are some functions (such as `xtan(x)dx` *[without limits]*) which can't be integrated, why? How can one understand which function is integrable or not?

Comment: A function is Riemann integrable if and only if the set of its discontinuities over the region of integration is of Lebesgue measure zero... By the way, $x\tan(x)dx$  is not a function; $x\tan(x)$ is. Also that $x\tan(x)$ is integrable on some regions, for example $[0,1]$.

Comment: The distinction between differentiation and integration can already be seen if you focus not on "is it integrable or not?" but "is it a rational function or not?".  The derivative of every rational function is a rational function, but the antiderivative of a rational function *need not* be a rational function, such as the functions $1/x$ or $1/(x^2+1)$.

Answer (score 4):

**Why doesn't every function have an antiderivative?**

Finding the indefinite integral of a function $f$, is the same as finding a function $F$ whose *derivative* is $f$. As explained [here](https://www.math.toronto.edu/mathnet/questionCorner/existantideriv.html), this requires $f$ to be *continuous*.

If $f$ is discontinuous, then there may be some value $x$ such that $f(x)$ is undefined. When this happens, it means that $F'(x)$ does not exist, i.e. $F$ is not differentiable at $x$.

There are ways around this, however. For example, you can remove discontinuities or restrict the domain of $f$ so that it is continuous. There are increasingly obscure methods which can be used to integrate discontinuous functions, but I don't know much about them.

Stretching the definition of "integration" to its utmost extreme, I wouldn't be surprised if *every* function can be integrated.

**Why can't every antiderivative be expressed in terms of elementary functions?**

The integral of $x\tan(x)$ (ignoring discontinuities) is:

$$\frac{i}{2}(\text{Li}_2(-e^{2 i x}) + x (x + 2 i \ln(1 + e^{2 i x}))) + c$$

Where $i$ is the imaginary unit, and $\text{Li}_2$ is the [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) of order 2. This is a *special function*, and cannot be expressed in terms of *elementary functions*.

The reason that antiderivatives cannot always be expressed in terms of elementary functions is that the set of elementary functions is not closed under limits in general. The specific fact that the integral of an elementary function is not always an elementary function is known as [Liouville's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra)).